# How to over ride the get context data method in view

Tags: python, django

I am currently trying to create a like button for my posts in Django

I have reached to the part where I can add a like but I am facing difficulty writing the code related to the view which linking the PostListView if there is user who liked it or not. I am getting an error:

```
Exception Value:    
name 'post' is not defined
```

Here is my Model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    designer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='likes')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("score:post-detail", kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Here is my  URL

```
path('like/', like_post, name='like_post'),
```

Here is the updated views code:

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "score.html"
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(admin_approved=True)
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=self.request.POST.get('post_id'))
        context = super(PostListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['posts'][0].likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists()
        is_liked = False
        if post.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            is_liked = True
        context['is_like'] = is_liked
        return context


def like_post(request):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
    is_liked = False
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        posts.likes.remove(request.user)
        is_liked = False

    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        is_liked = True

    return HttpResponseRedirect(post.get_absolute_url())
```

here is the template

```
{% extends "base.html"%} {% block content %} {% for post in posts %}

<div style="padding-top: 200 px;"><strong>{{post.title}}</strong></div>

<form action="{% url 'score:like_post'%}" method="POST" class="ui form">
  {% csrf_token %} {% if is_like %}
  <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{{post.id}}" />
  <button class="ui button positive" type="submit">Unlike</button>
  {% else %}
  <button class="ui button negative" type="submit">Like</button>
  {% endif %}
</form>
<strong>Likes </strong>

{% endfor %} {% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "score.html"
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(admin_approved=True)
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)          _____________________
        is_liked = False                                                       |
        if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():               <-----| I Think the issue is 
            is_liked = True                                                    |      with this code
        context = {'post': post,                                               |
                   'is_like': is_liked,                                        |
                   }                                                           |_____________________
        return context
```

like you mentioned, the issue is in this code,

```
post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
```

this line causes the error. you are calling **post.likes.filter** , but you haven't defined a variable **post**.

since the view is a **ListView** , you can get list of all posts from **context['posts']** after the super method. and you can call **context['posts'][0].likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists()** to get the details of first post,

or if you want to check for a specific post, use **DetailView** instead of **ListView**

Hope this helps

Edit:

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "score.html"
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(admin_approved=True)
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=self.request.POST.get('post_id'))
        context = super(PostListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['posts'][0].likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists()
        is_liked = False
        if post.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            is_liked = True
        context['is_like'] = is_liked
        return context
```

replace the above code with the below code.

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "score.html"
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(admin_approved=True)
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        post = context['posts'][0]
        is_liked = False
        if post.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            is_liked = True
        context['current_post'] = post
        context['is_like'] = is_liked
        return context
```

Comment: I have defined post and add the context as you highlighted but i am getting ` name 'request' is not defined `

Comment: use self.request

Comment: I am searching for the reason for getting another error after your current updates now I am getting `Page not found (404)`

Comment: is there a post with the post_id you are passing with the request

Comment: I added it to the question

Comment: context = {'post': post,                                               |
                   'is_like': is_liked,                                        |
                   }   

change the above code

Comment: add context['is_like'] = is_liked

Comment: I am getting the same error for the updated the code in the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213782/discussion-between-sachin-whiteman-d-and-ahmed-khairy).

Comment: can you please print the request.POST.get(''post_id") , and comment here